# Why do Android 13 NFC readers no long recognize credit cards?

Tags: nfc

My NFC reader app (as well as several downloaded from Play) no longer detects credit cards on devices running Android 13 (Pixel 4a & Pixel 6a).  No problems on devices running Android 12 (eg, Pixel 3a).  My app recognizes ndef, isodep, mifare,nfc[abv].

On Android 13, only NDEF tags trigger discovery.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot confirm this - on my Samsung A52 with Android 13 running a downloaded app and 2 self-programmed apps can read a credit card without no problem. The only experience on my side is that the NFC filed seems to be weaker so I have to place the card's antenna exactly over the device NFC-chip/antenna.

Comment: you're right!  if i take my android 13 devices out of their cases and jam the card into the back of the device, and move very slowly until i hit the right spot, then 2 discover credit cards trigger discovery by app.  still no luck with visa.  but thanks for the heads up